# How can I add an array/hash in a custom log in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, watchdog

I know Drupal 7 has a watchdog method to put a string into recent logs like

```
watchdog('php', 'error message');
```

How can I custom it and add an array/hash into the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following line:

```
watchdog('CUSTOM LOG', '<pre>'.print_r($yourArray, true).'</pre>');
```

And you can filter `CUSTOM LOG` in your recent logs as your own type.